# Combinatorial class and sum of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we get $99$ with $1,5,10,25$ (order doesn't matter)?

I have to do this using combinatorial class. I was thinking about creating one $A = \left \{ a,b,c,d \right \}$ where $\left \|a\right \|=1, \left \|b\right \|=5, \left \|c\right \|=10, \left \|d\right \|=25 $. Then $A(x)=x+x^5+x^{10}+x^{25}$. And now I'm stuck. I can't use $Seq(A)$ here, I mean order doesn't matter, and I'm not so sure how to get the ways of summing from that. I would appreciate if someone could explain that to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the notation of *Analytic Combinatorics*, I think the combinatorial class you want is
$$\mathcal{C} = SEQ(\mathcal{I}^{\{ 1 \}}) \;SEQ(\mathcal{I}^{\{ 5 \}}) \;SEQ(\mathcal{I}^{\{ 10 \}}) \;SEQ(\mathcal{I}^{\{ 25 \}})$$
where by definition $\mathcal{I}^{\{ 1 \}} = \{ \bullet \}$,
 $\mathcal{I}^{\{ 5 \}} = \{ \bullet \bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\}$,  etc.

In other words, a sequence of objects of size $1$, followed by a sequence of objects of size $5$, followed by a sequence of objects of size $10$, followed by a sequence of objects of size $25$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way, using brute force, is to consider 0,5,...,95 (since the amount of 1's will be uniquely determined in all such cases).  So for example 1 way when 0 (99 "1's"), 1 way when 5 (1 "5" and 94 "1's"), 2 ways when 10 (1 "10"  94 "1's" and 2 "5's" 94 "1's")…   maybe after you do several of these you will discover a pattern.

Comment: I'm not good at something like this... isn't there another way, I was thinking about using $Mset(A)$ and somehow get sets which elements sum to 99 but I'm not sure if it's good way, still I don't know how to count this.